# Failed to construct 'Comment

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. I want to print out an array of objects in the view.

In my render() method of App component, I tried this:

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
       Your data:
       {
         this.props.val.map(
           (s, i) => 
              <Details key={i} data={s} />
          )
       }
  </div>
);
}
```

And In Details Component:

```
class Details extends Comment{
rendeer(){
return (
  <div>
     <span>{this.props.data.name} {this.props.data.cgpa}</span> 
  </div>
);
}};
```

Note: Both the components are in the same file. And i am facing this error=>
[image: ErroMessage]

But if i do this instead of calling details component:

```
Your data:<br />
       {
         this.props.val.map(
           (s, i) => 
           <p key={i}>{s.name} {s.cgpa}</p> 
          )
       }
```

It works perfectly fine.

Comment: Where did you define `Comment` class? Shouldn't it be `Component` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo **`rendeer()`**. It should be **`render()`**.

I think you mistyped **`Comment`**, it should be **`Component`**. Like :

```
import React, {Component} from react;

class Details extends Component {
  // ...
}
```